# Use C++-Iterators on Python-List with the Python/C API?

Tags: c++, python, iterator, python-c-api, stl-algorithm

Is it possible to use the tools only needing `Iterators` and a function-pointer from the module `<algorithm>` on `PyObjects` ?

The concrete problem I want to solve (it is constructed to learn from it):

- I have a huge list of IDs stored in a python-list
- Now I want to perform a `std::binary_search` on this list, using a module written in C++

One way could be to access the python-list as c-array, constructing a vector from it (which uses the pointers/ does not copy), doing the binary_search and export the array as `PyObject`.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a binary search isn't that complicated, so why don't you simply code one based on a range of indices instead of iterators? I believe that a list conforms to the [sequence protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html) of Python, so that should be pretty easy.

If you really want to use the `binary_search()` algorithm for a learning experience, there is also the possibility to create STL-style iterators on top of the Python sequence. All you need is a pointer to the sequence and an index to create a random-access iterator. If you want to, you can also transparently convert the Python objects in the list into an according ID type (some integer type, I guess).

```
struct iterator
{
    // typedefs required for fully compliant STL-style iterators
    typedef PyObject* value_type;

    iterator(PyObject* seqeunce, Py_ssize_t position):
        m_sequence(sequence), m_position(position)
    {
        assert(PySequence_Check(m_sequence));
        assert(m_position >= 0);
        assert(m_position <= PySequence_GetSize(m_sequence));
    }
    value_type operator*() const
    {
        assert(m_position < PySequence_GetSize(m_sequence));
        return PySequence_GetItem(m_sequence, m_position);
    }
    iterator& operator++()
    {
        assert(m_position <= PySequence_GetSize(m_sequence));
        ++m_position;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator& operator+=(size_t l)
    {
        m_position += l;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I haven't compiled this and probably forgot a few parts, but I guess you get the idea. Just init two iterators, one with an offset of zero and one with an offset of the size of the container and give those to `binary_search()`.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating how to wrap this up as an iterator. You say, "a binary search isn't that complicated", but like Donald Knuth says, "although the basic idea of binary search is comparatively straightforward, the details can be surprisingly tricky…". No matter how much a binary search is conceptually simple, using std::binary_search instead of rolling a custom implementation is a really good idea. =)

Comment: Actually, there's [evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Implementation_issues) that binary search is among the *hardest* algorithms to get completely right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the hint I needed! You can find a working implementation at https://github.com/zvynar/CModuleForPython.